# Processing speed over mounted path

Tags: linux, unix, networking, network-programming, distributed-computing

I have two scenarios.

Scenario 1: Machine A contains 1000 documents as folders. This folder of machine A is mounted in machine B. I process documents within these folders in machine B and store the output result in mounted path in machine B.

Scenario 2: The documents in machine A is directly copied into machine B and processed

Scenario 2 is much faster than Scenario 1. I could guess its because there is no data transfer happening over the network between 2 machines. Is there a way I can use mounting and still achieve better performance?

Comment: I don't think so.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you try enabling a cache? - for NFS: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/fscachenfs.html - CIFS should have caching enabled by default (unless you disabled it)

The other option would be to use something like Windows’ offline files, which copies files and folders between client and server in the background, so you don’t need to deal with it. The only thing I’ve found for linux is [OFS](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2009/99/Offline-FS).

But the performance depends on the size of the files and if you read them randomly or sequentially. For instance when I am encoding videos, I access the file right away via the network from my NFS, because it takes as much time as it would take to read and write the file. This way no additional time is “wasted” on the encoding, as the application can encode the stream which is coming from the network.

So for large files you might want to change the algorithms to a sequential read, on the other hand small files which are copied within seconds, could be also synced between server and client using rsync, bittorrent sync, dropbox or one of the other hundreds of tools. And this is actually quite commonly done.